# Are there more recent and more scientifically valid alternatives to MMPI?

Tags: test

Are there any other newer / more sophisticated and valid test useful in a diagnosis and further treatment of clinical problems?

I'm interested in clinical diagnosis.

Comment: Imagine, after a cognitive therapy the MMPI test fails to recognize other problems of the subject.

But the subject seems to be still affected by:

- Narcissism
- Stubbornness
- Mental Rigidity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In clinical psychology, two kinds of *general* personality tests are in use today.

One kind of test is not a specialized clinical test but tests personality in general. These tests are used outside of clinical contexts as well. There are many models of personality and a multitude of tests to measure personality according to each model, but the most popular model of general personality today is the [Big Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) or Five Factor model, and one of the most valid and reliable tests for this model is the [NEO-PI-R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEO-PI-R).

The other kind of test is one that tests for symptoms of psychological disorders according to one of the two popular diagnostic manuals, the [Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnostic_and_Statistical_Manual_of_Mental_Disorders) and the [International Statistical Classification of Diseases and Related Health Problems (ICD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Statistical_Classification_of_Diseases_and_Related_Health_Problems). The most popular test today is probably the [Structured Clinical Interview for DSM-IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_Clinical_Interview_for_DSM-IV).

Besides these general tests, clinicians will use one or more tests to measure specific aspects of personality or specific symptoms, according to their impression of the patient or a diagnosis given by the refering phyisician, psychiatrist or psychologist. These specialised tests are too numerous to list here.